# Why don't the border line in both Google AD and ToolBar display in Android?

Tags: android

I have set `<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />` for the RelativeLayout, I think that the border with width="1dp" is for whole screen.

But I find the top of screen (AdView -> android:id="@+id/adView")  don't display border line ,and the bottom of screen (LinearLayout -> android:id="@+id/ToolBar") don't display border line too,
only the center of screen (LinearLayout -> android:id="@+id/MyCenter") display border line? Why?

I hope the full screen display border line, how can I do that? Thanks!

**Current**
[image]

**I hope**
[image]

**border_ui.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

**cleanup_about.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:paddingTop="12dip"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingRight="7dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/appversion"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myabout"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMyLink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:text="@string/mylink" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnReturn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use margin of 1 dp for your adview and the toolbar linear layout. It will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! Your code works, but I don't know why I need set  margin=1,  the relativeLayout is most outer and all others layout must be inner relativeLayout